# How navigate to page with tabs in Ionic 4 using Angular Router?

Tags: angular6, ionic4

I've just created a Ionic 4 app using the Ionic CLI, using the tabs template. My biggest issue is how to navigate from a root Login Page (without tabs) to Home Page (with tabs) and **keep showing the tabs** on bottom.

My `app-routing.module.ts`, looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }
];
```

And on my `login.page.ts` I'm doing the following command after a successful login:

```
this.router.navigate(['tabs']);
```

I also changed the last object's `path` property on `tabs.router.module.ts`:

```
  {
    path: '/tabs',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

But, at runtime, after navigating to the Tabs Page it **only shows the Home Page without any tabs** on the bottom the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a solution:

The last object on the **const routers** in `tabs.router.module.ts` should redirect to login, like so:

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

Then it's just keep the Tabs as root rout in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' }
];
```